# Use triton audio player with react native

Tags: react-native

I have to use an audio player, triton player

https://userguides.tritondigital.com/spc/moband/index.html
that allows using a sdk for android as a music player, How could I use it with react native

I found this module: react-triton-digital-player
but I couldn't make it work a js file must be imported

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-triton-digital-player
-prerequisites:

-Install
yarn add react-triton-digital-player

-import
import Player from 'react-triton-digital-player';

-my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import Player from 'react-triton-digital-player';

export default function App(){

  const onAdBlockerDetected = async ()=> {
        console.log('AdBlockerDetected');
  }

  const setExternalProps = async (props)=> {
        console.log(props);
  }
  const params = {
    station: 'YOUR_STATION',
    options: {
      setExternalProps: setExternalProps(),
      onAdBlockerDetected: onAdBlockerDetected(),
      autoPlay: true
    }
  };
  return(
    
    
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View styles={{ flex: 1}}>
        <Text>MY APP</Text>
      </View>
      <View styles={{ flex: 1}}>
        <Text>
          <Player params={params} />
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
      flex: 1,
      padding: 0,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
   },
    
});
```

this gives an error apparently for not being able to import:

```
Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.
```

Comment: It's not strange that react-triton-digital-player doesn't work as this is a react library that provides react components, not react native components. The `Player` component renders some div's for example and there are no div's in react native so it will be interpreted by react native as text, which explains the error message.

Comment: thanks! @BasvanderLinden interpret as react js. 
I did not find a way to use native SDK in React Native

Answer (score -1):

You can use this package

https://github.com/Brianvdb/react-native-triton

This is the triton player for react-native

**Install**: `npm install react-native-triton-player`

**Use**: `import RNTritonPlayer from 'react-native-triton-player';`

**Play**: `RNTritonPlayer.play(tritonName, tritonMount)`

**Pause**: `RNTritonPlayer.pause()`

**Unpause**: `RNTritonPlayer.unPause()`

**Stop**: `RNTritonPlayer.stop()`

They provide some listeners also.